# Retry loop fails to find newly created file even though it is there

Tags: python

The following code creates the path:  `/Users/michellegautier/ACHFiles/26207428-8f40-11e7-8d57-f354c8f15cfa/outbox/PPSACHCOMSpec/mt.ach.06302020.??????_8172363248911097723`, or similar.

We are waiting for this file to be created.  In the initial `time.sleep(1)`, if I change it to `10`, the `if not os.path.isfile(filepath)` statement returns false as because it finds the file and everything works great.

BUT, if I shorten this time to `1` and the file isn't there yet, I'm trying to find it after it is created. Even if I add large pauses and ensure the file is created, the following `if os.path.isfile(filepath):` in the for loop NEVER passes and I don't know why.

I've tried adjusting the statements to exists, check for length of file, etc but no matter what, if it doesn't find it in the first check, it never finds the file in subsequent checks even after it is added.  Please help!

```
home = str(Path.home())
file_date = strftime('%m%d%Y')
if company_profile == 'from_storage':
    company_profile = context.storage['company_profile_id']
filepath = home + '/ACHFiles/' + context.providerID + '/outbox/PPSACHCOMSpec/mt.ach.' + file_date + '.??????_{}'.format(
            company_profile)
       
time.sleep(int(1))
for name in glob.glob(filepath):
    filepath = name

if not os.path.isfile(filepath):
for i in range(3):
    time.sleep(3)
    if os.path.isfile(filepath):
        print('File found:    ', filepath)
        break
```

Comment: Pretty sure you're misdiagnosing the problem here. `filepath = name` just overwrites the `filepath` on each iteration and all you're left with is the last one. I don't see where you're creating the file

Comment: Please [edit] the post to get the indentation correct and make sure we have a full [mcve]

Comment: @roganjosh,  thank you for the feedback.  I am not creating the file in my code.  I've launched a process that does that and in this code I'm ready to read that file.

Comment: There is no retry loop.

Comment: @JanChristophTerasa `for i in range(3):` is the retry loop.

Comment: What if three iterations aren't enough? Is it intentional to just move on after 9 seconds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with your use of `glob.glob()`. It will only return files that already exist. If none of the matching files exist when you start, `glob.glob()` won't return anything, and `filepath` will still be set to the wildcard. `os.path.isfile()` doesn't do wildcard matching, so it will never succeed.

You need to call `glob.glob()` in the retry loop, not before the loop.

```
max_retries = 4
time.sleep(1)
for _ in range(max_retries):
    files = glob.glob(filepath):
    if len(files) > 0:
        filepath = files[-1]
        print("File found: " + filepath)
        break
    time.sleep(3)
else:
    print("File not found")
```

Comment: That fixed it.  Thank you so much for explaining it!